# How to check-not add duplicates with EF from a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I have an `IEnumerable ORDERS` that I get from reading from an excel file. Then I add each row:

```
foreach (var item in so)
{
       context.ORDERS.AddObject(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Sometimes there are duplicates in the source file, and I'm not sure how to not add duplicates to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to not add duplicates to the table.

Check whether the `ORDERS` list already contains the `item` or not before add it to the list. Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) for example like this:

```
foreach (var item in so)
{
    //If ORDERS List doesn't contain any item with the same id 
    //or any other predicate match
    if(!context.ORDERS.Any(o => o.Id == item.Id)) //or any other property of item
       context.ORDERS.AddObject(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```